# How customize results in Recoll?

Tags: recoll

Please tell me how to display in the result sheet the full string of the word you are looking for, and not in pieces as in default in Recoll,I'll try in more detail:
I have recoll installed on my computer (which uses Xapian).
There are so many files.
I want to use recall as an alternative to grep
I indexed my data and search, but in the resultant window I do not like the output:
I want the whole row to be highlighted as if in a grepe, where I have the search word and output it immediately to the Result Sheet.
And now it looks like it gives out a piece of text where the searched word is found, but only partially, then it is divided by several points and again a piece of text, and again. You can see an example in the image, for example here (default settings) https://i0.wp.com/www.linuxlinks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Screenshot-Recoll.jpg?resize=768%2C596&ssl=1

Comment: Pls add some code or example to  tell what you want

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I didn’t explain it well. I'll try in more detail:
I have recoll installed on my computer.
There are so many files.
I want to use recoll as an alternative to grep.
I indexed my data and search, but in the result window I do not like the output:
I want the whole row to be highlighted as if in a grep, where I have the search word and output it immediately to the result list.

Comment: And now it looks like it gives out a piece of text where the searched word is found, but only partially, then it is divided by several points and again a piece of text, and again.You can see an example in the image, for example here (default settings) https://i0.wp.com/www.linuxlinks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Screenshot-Recoll.jpg?resize=768%2C596&ssl=1

Answer (score 0):

This is how recoll works. It shows you "snippets" of text around the search hits. You can adjust the snippets parameters (size and number of context words) in the preferences Gui Configuration, Search Parameters section. You can also hit Preview, and then shift down/up arrows, to browse the result documents previews, for a more complete view.

Comment: In which file does recoll save customizations of appearance?

Answer (score 0):

As medoc indicated, this is how recoll works.  You can get a somewhat better output by searching for phrases and signaling recoll that you want an exact match The highlighting would need to be triggered in whatever tool is providing you with the output.

I wasn't satisfied with the desktop app and the Python web interface became too slow at around 20K documents, so I wrote a CGI wrapper for the recoll binary.  Its speed is still acceptable at my current 38K documents (mostly PDFs).  Extraction takes about 40 minutes (roughly 1K documents per minute), but query speeds are still less than a second. If there's interest, I'll drop the Dockerfile and K8S manifests on Github.